# Openstack path traversal guidelines docs has a broken example. What went wrong?

Tags: python, openstack, path-traversal

https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_using-file-paths.html

If I try to run the given code from the above link:

```
import os

def is_safe_path(basedir, path, follow_symlinks=True):
    # resolves symbolic links
    if follow_symlinks:
         matchpath = os.path.realpath(path).startswith(basedir)
    else:
         matchpath = os.path.abspath(path).startswith(basedir)
    return basedir == os.path.commonpath((basedir, matchpath))

is_safe_path('/test', '/test/../abc')
```

It clearly does not work:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Mar  4 2021, 21:24:42)
[GCC 10.2.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>>
>>> def is_safe_path(basedir, path, follow_symlinks=True):
...     # resolves symbolic links
...     if follow_symlinks:
...          matchpath = os.path.realpath(path).startswith(basedir)
...     else:
...          matchpath = os.path.abspath(path).startswith(basedir)
...     return basedir == os.path.commonpath((basedir, matchpath))
...
>>> is_safe_path('/test', '/test/../abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in is_safe_path
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 496, in commonpath
    paths = tuple(map(os.fspath, paths))
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not bool
```

What's the spurious bit of code here?
Should the `.startswith()` be removed?
Am I totally misunderstanding what the purpose of having a boolean in the tuple is?

I found the edit where this was changed:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ossa/+bug/1815422
https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/ossa/+/771854/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo in the code, `.startswith(basedir)` isn't meant to follow `realpath` or `abspath`. Most likely a copy and paste issue to be honest. I would highly recommend that you submit a fix for the issue!